# Adding data to a SQL table through a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures

I'm working on a learning project to understanding SQL. And one of the tasks I was given is:

For the "Create Order" button, create a stored procedure named [dbo].[CreateOrder] that creates a new order for the selected product and decrements the quantity of product in stock. If there is not enough product in stock to create the order the procedure should return a message stating so.

For this question I am given a DB that has several tables in it, but I'm not sure what the correct approach to solving this task is.

Comment: ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eJjzH.jpg

Comment: use the above comment to look at the database structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty vague question, but I'd solve it with the following steps:

1) Creating a stored procedure that accepts parameters needed for the order.

2) Declare a varchar variable in the stored procedure to hold feedback for the user.

3) Using those parameters, check for product availability with a SELECT query in the stored procedure.

3) If the product is available, add the order to the appropriate table by adding an INSERT query to the stored procedure, and set the feedback variable to let the user know the order was inserted.

4) If the product is not available, set your feedback variable to say so.

5) Return the feedback variable to the user.

If you don't know how to perform any of those individual steps, hopefully that at least breaks the problem down into manageable bites to look up.

Comment: Thanks! This should help quite a bit. I do know most of the stuff you described, just wasn't sure how to put it all together.